Integrating Flask into geoprocessing service
I'm working on a customized geoprocessing service that I’m publishing from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Server. My goal is to configure this service to work as a webhook, so that it can directly receive incoming HTTP POST requests, take the request body as input, and then parse and process it.
In previous projects, I used the Flask framework to handle incoming POST requests, but I’d like to know if ArcGIS Server’s Python environment has native support for handling these requests, or if I need to install a third-party library like Flask to accomplish this.
How do I set this up?

This already has a great an accepted answer. I want to ask why you want to use a GP Service as a webhook receiver? While technically you can, in my opinion this is not using the right tools for the job. The GP Service framework is heavy and great for arcpy level things. Webhook receivers should be light and responsive. As suggested, use Flask and pass the request to the GP Service (if arcpy is necessary), else stay 100% flask and no GP Service.

Your geoprocessing service code does not have access to the incoming HTTP request directly. ArcGIS Server parses the HTTP request for you and only passes the input parameter data to the python script. The requests must conform to the schema of the /execute or /submitJob API, depending whether your service is synchronous or asynchronous.
If a GP service on its own is not capable of serving as your webhook, you could create a custom Flask app (hosted separately from ArcGIS Server) that handles the incoming request and makes its own calls to the GP service as needed.
